# Find missing data in pandas dataframe and fill with NA

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas with company name and date as multi-index.

```
companyname date emp1 emp2 emp3..... emp80
```

Where emp1, emp2 is the count of phone calls made by emp1 and 2 respectively on that date. Now there are dates when no employee made a call. Means there are rows where all the column values are 0. I want to fill these values by NA. 
Should I manually write the names of all columns in some function? Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check that the entire row is 0 with all:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [0, 4], [0, 0], [7, 8]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  0  4
2  0  0
3  7  8

In [13]: (df == 0).all(1)
Out[13]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Now you can assign all the entries in these rows to NaN using loc:

```
In [14]: df.loc[(df == 0).all(1)] = np.nan

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
    0   1
0   1   2
1   0   4
2 NaN NaN
3   7   8
```